# How to add Corporate News OOTB on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

How can I create any sort of Announcement list in Office365 SharePoint online. Here I wanted to

Corporate News section will be created on the Corporate Intranet for Marketing to publish all corporate news. SharePoint OOTB news will be used.

In 2013 we had  Announcements List (OOTB) where we can add all this related stuff but here in SharePoint online I couldn't find any corporate/announcement list. Where specific people can place news and it can be displayed on dashboard or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this question, just to enable the following feature on my subsite:

- Team Collaboration Lists

Follow below steps to enable this feature:

1. Click on Setting icon on top right corner.
2. Select Site Actions.
3. Select Manage site features.
4. Enable the above mentioned feature.

Once this feature is enabled you can click on the `+` icon inside site content there you will find all the Announcements, Calendar, News and all other extra stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this using old SharePoint announcements list, then

go to **Site Contents** => click on plus icon (**+**) => click on **App** => here you will get the list templates like in SP2013.

Or

By using Modern Pages.  To create modern page,

go to **Site Pages** library => click on plus icon and click on **Site Page**. This will create a modern page. Go to the page, click on plus icon. It will show a small menu with options to add on the page. Select **News** and a news webpart will appear on the page. Click on "add news" button to add news on the page.

If the list template does not appear in the Apps, then check if you have "Edit" or greater permission on the subsite. If you have the necessary permissions and still the list templates do not appear, the try this:
Go to "**Site Settings**" => "**Manage site features**" under Site Actions => check if **Team Collaboration Lists** feature is active. If not then Activate this feature and try creating the Announcement list.

Comment: Yes that is what I'm doing clicked the + icon but here I cannot find anything. But I've just checked all these things are available in my main site. I think there is some sort of feature which I need to enable in my subsite. All these options are available in main root site

Comment: Do you have Edit or greater permission on the subsite?

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth looking at the new communications site template for your news requirements. There is a new content type for news as well as a news and highlighted content filter web part. See this article https://en.share-gate.com/blog/5-ways-to-manage-news-in-office-365